# How do you position and fix a navigation bar to the center of a page? (CSS/Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I'm struggling to fix a navigation bar to the center of a page using CSS and/or Bootstrap. I'd like it to be centered horizontally and vertically. I'm also trying to make sure that any content published below the nav bar doesn't affect its position.

Could someone please advise on how I achieve this?

Here's my HTML so far:

```
<body>
            <div id="all-rows">
                <div id="row">
                    <div class="container-fluid" id="navbar">
                        <div class="container text-center">
                            <h1>Welcome!</h1>
                                <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" onclick="loadAbout()">about</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="">social</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="">scripts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="">contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="row">
                    <p class="container-fluid" id="placeholder-bottom">&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#placeholder-bottom {
   position: relative;
   width: 60%;
   padding: 2%;
   margin: auto;
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  }
  
#navbar {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

At the moment, the content is centered horizontally but not vertically. The closest I've come is to be able to put it centrally using "position: absolute" however the content below the navbar overlaps the navbar when in mobile view.

I'd be incredibly grateful for any help! (Newbie here!)

Thanks!

Comment: It is center horizontally and vertically as you've expected. https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/vYyzPoY?editors=1100

Comment: Hi, the code you have given works fine to center your navbar so perhaps you could show us more so we can see what is affecting it/what it is affecting in the rest of your page? Is something else set as fixed or similar??